# Cart stock return query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that must do the following:

- select all items from shopping carts with ID=0
- update corresponding products with selected quantities

My query stops working when there are more than one items in shopping cart with the same product. For instance:

```
product1|quantity X
product2|quantity Y
product1|quantity Z
```

Here's the query (i think the table structure is pretty clear from the query itself):

```
UPDATE ct_products AS P
JOIN ct_shopping_cart_products AS SCP ON (SCP.product = P.id)
SET P.stockQty = P.stockQty + SCP.qty, -- update product stock QTY by QTY from cart products
SCP.qty=0 -- reset QTY on the product in shopping cart
WHERE SCP.cart=0; -- only from carts with ID=0
```

I don't quite understand the inner workings of joins in updates well so i guess this is probably a very simple problem that an expert can solve easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
UPDATE ct_products AS P
JOIN ct_shopping_cart_products AS SCP ON (SCP.product = P.id)
JOIN (SELECT product,cart,SUM(qty) as qty FROM ct_shopping_cart_products
      GROUP BY product,cart) AS SCP2 ON (SCP.product = SCP2.product
                                     AND SCP.cart = SCP2.cart)
SET 
P.stockQty = P.stockQty + SCP2.qty, 
SCP.qty=0 
WHERE SCP.cart=0
```

This query will update using `SCP2.qty` which is a SUM of qty GROUPED BY product and cart.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23b3d/1)

Comment: I thought your query would've done it but I guess not. Trial and error.